# Assert that derived class methods are called in correct order

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm trying to verify that the implementation of **Base.run_this** calls the methods of derived class (derived_method_[1st|2nd|3rd]) in correct order. As the output shows, the test is not working. How can I fix this?

```
class Base(object):
  __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

  def __init__(self, parameters):
   self.parameters = parameters;

  @abc.abstractmethod
  def must_implement_this(self):
   return

  def run_this(self):
   self.must_implement_this()
   if(self.parameters):
    first = getattr(self, "derived_method_1st")
    first()
    second = getattr(self, "derived_method_2nd")
    second()
    third = getattr(self, "derived_method_3rd")
    third()

class Derived(Base):
  def must_implement_this(self):
   pass
  def derived_method_1st(self):
   pass
  def derived_method_2nd(self):
   pass
  def derived_method_3rd(self):
   pass

mocked = MagicMock(wraps=Derived(True))
mocked.run_this()
mocked.assert_has_calls([call.derived_method_1st(), call.derived_method_2nd(), call.derived_method_3rd()])
```

### Output

```
AssertionError: Calls not found.
  Expected: [call.derived_method_1st(), call.derived_method_2nd(),   call.derived_method_3rd()]
  Actual: [call.run_this()]
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Either `derived_method`s are public and you should test each one of them, or they are private and you should test `must_implement_this` without even taking to consideration internal structure of  method. Test against interface, not implementation details. Is it an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

`wraps` doesn't work well with *instances*. What happens here is that `mocked.run_this` returns a new mock object that 'wraps' `Derived(True).run_this`, where the latter is a bound method to the *original* `Derived()` instance.

As such, that method will call `self.derived_method_*` methods that are bound to that original instance, not to the mock.

You could patch in the `run_this` method on a `spec` mock instead:

```
mock = MagicMock(spec=Derived)
instance = mock()
instance.run_this = Derived.run_this.__get__(instance)  # bind to mock instead
instance.parameters = True  # adjust as needed for the test
instance.run_this()
```

Demo:

```
>>> mock = MagicMock(spec=Derived)
>>> instance = mock()
>>> instance.run_this = Derived.run_this.__get__(instance)  # bind to mock instead
>>> instance.parameters = True  # adjust as needed for the test
>>> instance.run_this()
>>> instance.mock_calls
[call.must_implement_this(),
 call.derived_method_1st(),
 call.derived_method_2nd(),
 call.derived_method_3rd()]
```